# Do antibiotics contribute to bone healing?

Tags: antibiotics, bones, broken-bones

Two weeks ago I broke my tibia in an accident. First I was taken to a hospital near the place where the accident happened, and the doctor gave me two options, either putting a plaster or inserting a rod(which he highly recommended). Due to some reasons, I had to choose the plaster.

The doctor at this first hospital gave me a prescription which contained the following tablets:

- Calcium Citrate with Vitamin D3 tablets
- Levofloxacin tablets (Levosel - 500)
- Pantoprazole (Pantosel 40)
- Diclofinac sodium with Paracetamol
- Paracetamol

The next day I went to another hospital in my home town, and they suggested removing the plaster to insert the rod. And so it was, I had a surgery to insert the rods.

The doctor at this hospital gave me a prescription which only contained the following tablets that I have been taking:

- Pantoprazole tablets(Pavonib-40)
- Cefixime dicloxacillin and lactic acid bacillus tablets (CEFIWOK XL -200 )
- Paracetamol

Although he did not see the medicine given to me in the other hospital when I asked what to do with it, he simply told me to not take any of the tablets prescribed in the first hospital.

Which brings me to my question:

Does calcium and/or vitamin D help in the healing of bone fractures?

Do antibiotics help in the healing of bone fractures?

Comment: I edited your question heavily because it appeared to be a request for personal medical advice. If you disagree with my edits you can undo them, but be aware that if you do it's very likely your question will be closed.

Answer (score 1):

[The antibiotics may have been, because you had surgery.](http://orthoinfo.aaos.org/topic.cfm?topic=A00580)

- They broke skin
- Introduce new particles to the body
- Your bone was already broken

**Since infection can lead to prolonged healing, you could see it working that way.**

[Fluoroquinolones](http://fqresearch.org/antibiotic-bone-fracture) are known to negatively affect bone growth, this is mostly seen in infants though.

[The effect of antibiotics on bone healing: current evidence](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/21824037)

---

[Livestrong.com](http://www.livestrong.com/article/454689-what-are-the-benefits-of-calcium-supplements-in-fracture-healing/)

- Vitamin D increases Calcium absorption
- Calcium increases bone density

[The effect of calcium and vitamin D3 supplementation on the healing of the proximal humerus fracture](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/15386160):

**Results of study:**

> we have demonstrated that it is possible to quantify callus formation
>   of the PHF with sufficiently high precision to demonstrate the
>   positive influence of vitamin D3 and calcium over the first 6 weeks
>   after fracture

All in all Vitamin D, Calcium, and antibiotics all do in a way help bone fracture healing.